# Deploy Django App to Heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

```
    Pushing to git@heroku.com:lebab.git

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Python/Django app detected
-----> Preparing Python interpreter (2.7.2)
-----> Creating Virtualenv version 1.7.2
       New python executable in .heroku/venv/bin/python2.7
       Also creating executable in .heroku/venv/bin/python
```

*** omission　***

```
    -----> Discovering process types

         !     Heroku push rejected due

 to an unrecognized error.
     !     We've been notified, see http://support.heroku.com if the problem persists.


    To git@heroku.com:lebab.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:lebab.git'
```

I made django application, so I tried to deploy it to heroku.
and get the error.
what's mean? any ideas? 
If should I give more info, I will.

Comment: Any relevant output in `heroku logs`?

Comment: heroku logs said "ognized error". what's this?

Comment: "unrecognized error"?  All I can suggest is that you search StackOverflow for "heroku unrecognized error" and look at what other people have done.  If all else fails, do what the error message above says and file a ticket with support!

Answer (score 0):

just manage.py + requirements.txt are needed... :|